# In volleyball, we say "She slapped the ball" or "She hit the ball"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> ​[transitive] **[slap somebody/something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slap_1?q=slap) (+ adv./prep.)** to hit
>   somebody/something with the flat part of your hand synonym smack
>
> She slapped his face hard.
>
> She slapped him hard across the face.
>
> ‘Congratulations!’ he said, slapping me on the back.

Clearly, volleyball players hit the ball using the flat part of their hands.

My question is:

In volleyball, we say "***She slapped the ball away from the blockers to the corner***" or "***She hit the ball away from the blockers to the corner***"

Answer (score 1):

In Volleyball you don't tend to hit the ball with the flat palm of the hand. Not like you would slap someone on the face. You use other parts of the hand. Which is more like a "hit". I you did hit he ball with the flat open palm, then you could say you slapped the ball.

You don't slap a baseball with a bat, unless you hit it with a flat board. If you said he slapped the baseball, that would be an insult.